# Get prev, current, next on MongoDB c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a Collection Students which Stores registered students data in MongoDB. It has StudentName, SaveDate etc. fields. I am displaying the details to my website from my .net framework WebAPI.
What I want to do is **Get StudentDetails with prev next student ID's by the order of SaveDate**.

My current query gets Student details by student id from below query,

```
var collection = StudentDB.Collection<Student>("StudyMaterials");
            var curfilter = Builders<Student>.Filter.Eq(x => x.studentID, studentID);
            studentDetails= collection.Find(curfilter).FirstOrDefault();
```

This is my **Student.cs** class,

```
   public class Student
{
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
public Guid StudentID {get; set;}

public string StudentName {get; set;}

[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
public Guid NextStudentID {get; set;}

[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
public Guid PrevStudentID {get; set;}
}
```

I want to use aggregation but don't know how to sort by multiple sort definitions on the aggregation framework.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think you need to keep the students like that. I suggest the following:

```
public class Student
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime SaveDate { get; set; }
}
```

You need to make sure that the documents are sorted by `SaveDate`. For instance, when inserting new students into the database you can do it like this:

```
var student = new Student
{
    Name = "Sara",
    SaveDate = DateTime.UtcNow
};
context.Students.InsertOne(student);
```

Now, you can get the documents with `Skip` and `Limit`:

```
var skip = 0;
var limit = 1;
var context = new MongoContext();
var filter = Builders<Student>.Filter.Empty;
var result = context.Students.Find(filter).Skip(skip).Limit(limit).FirstOrDefault();
```

Increment `skip` to get next and so on.

Comment: this method you mentioned only fetch single student data, What I need here is the student with whose id I am fetching with Id of students inserted after and before this student. I need these in a single filter also.